# Clickfunnels "Vimeo is not defined" ERROR when using Vimeo Player.js API

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

Hi I'm using this Vimeo API ( https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/ ) and they have this snippet of code below as a test. The code work fine when I test it locally but I need to add the snippet to Clickfunnels and I'm getting an error. **See Image Below**

Any help on why this is happening would be appreciated.

```js
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('play', function() {
        console.log('played the video!');
    });

    player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('title:', title);
    });
</script>
```

[image: Clickfunnels Support Response Image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like this is more a clickfunnels issue rather than a Vimeo/JS as it works just fine in a "normal" environment.  I would add that tag to your question for the right audience.

Comment: I think there is an inconsistency in the vimeo documentation. I got it to work by calling it as Player, not Vimeo. new Player(..)